# Rails 4 Delegate user profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have three models : `Partner` & `User`, with standard data (:firstname, :lastname, :email, etc), and an `Event` model

**Use**

A User can create an Event, then Add Partners to the Event, by the help of a `EventsPartner` join table, the order of the Partners are saved in an additional row named 'Rank'

**Need**

I want a User to request ownership of the Partner profile, then User profile will be displayed instead of Partner profile, and the initial order of appearance must be respected.

When the User take ownership on the Partner, partners.delegate receive true (as an alternative, delegate could be the id of the User)

Filtering can be made with the email address (partners and owners have the same email)

**Sum up**

- User 1 create an Event
- User 1 add Partners A, B, C to Event with emails a@gm.com, b@gm.com, c@gm.com
- User 2 with email a@gm.com ask ownership on Partner A with email @gm.com
- User 1 event will display User 2 infos instead of Partner A, keeping order of appearance from EventsPartner

So, in my `events#show` action I have for now :

```
def show # with delegate is boolean, true
event_partners = @event.partners.all
# order is stored in EventsPartner (:event_id, :partner_id, :rank)
event_partners_only = @event.partners.where(delegate: false)
event_users_only = @event.partners.where(delegate: true)
users_email = event_users_only.pluck(:email)
event_users_only = User.where(email: users_email)
# how can I display the Users and Partners in the right order
end

def show # with delegate takes owner id
event_partners = @event.partners.all
# order is stored in EventsPartner (:event_id, :partner_id, :rank)
event_partners_only = @event.partners.where(delegate: nil)
event_users_only = @event.partners.where.not(delegate: nil)
users_id = event_users_only.pluck(:id)
event_users_only = User.where(id: users_id)
# how can I display the Users and Partners in the right order
end
```

**So, for an Event I have :**

- Partner (id, email, delegate)
- User (id, email)
- EventsPartner (event_id, partner_id, rank)

**PROBLEM**

How can I properly print the list of the Partners attending an event, replacing the partners infos by the ones of the owner when option delegate is 1, and still maintaining the initial ordering ?

For now, I just replace the values of event_partners like this :
But I'm not pleased with this hack...

```
event_partners.each do |ep|
  if ep.delegate?
    eu = event_users_only.find(email: ep.email)
    ep.firstname = eu.firstname
    ep.lastname = eu.lastname
    ep.occupation = eu.occupation
    ep.vignettea.url(:square) = eu.vignettea.url(:square)
  end
end
```

Thank you for your help